# My comment form in django is not working ? It,s neithere sending data to the db nor it,s displaying those?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to make a comment form in django where people can comment below my pot ,I tried a lot of things but I am not getting a appropriate solution .I hope that I wil get this here.

Here,s my model for comment

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('app.Post', related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
```

Here,s the forms for Comment

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comments

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Comments
            fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
        'comment':forms.Textarea(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
        'name':forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'})

        }

Here,s the views.py code

    class BlogDetail(DetailView):
        model = Post
        context_object_name = 'blog_object'
        template_name = 'app/blog.html'

def add_comments(request, pk):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        text = request.POST['text']
        form = CommentForm()
        form.email = email
        form.text = text
        form.save()


        return render(request,'app/blog.html')
```

And finally here,s the comment section of my blog.html

```
<div id="comments" class="comments-area">
<div id="respond" class="comment-respond">
 <h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">Leave a Comment</h3>
<form action="#" method="post" id="commentform" class="comment-form" novalidate="">
 {% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group form-group-with-icon comment-form-email">
<input id="email" class="form-control" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email" value="" size="10" aria-required="true">
<div class="form-control-border"></div>
 <i class="form-control-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group form-group-with-icon comment-form-message">
<textarea id="comment" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Your 
Comment" cols="2" rows="8" aria-required="true" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
 <div class="form-control-border"></div>
 <i class="form-control-icon fa fa-comment"></i>
</div>
<p class="form-submit">
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Post Comment/">
</p>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model has not email field and you should check your form is valid or not then save it.

```
class InstallmentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InstallmentModel
        fields = ['nationalNumber']

#if use FormView
class InstallmentView(generic.FormView):
    form_class = InstallmentForm

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super(InstallmentView, self).form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # statements
        return super(InstallmentView, self).form_valid(form)
```

or you can pass your data in form then validate it:

```
class InstallmentView(generic.TemplateView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        nationalNumber = request.POST['nationalNumber']

        form = InstallmentForm(data={
            'nationalNumber': nationalNumber
        })

        if form.is_valid():
            InstallmentModel.objects.create(
               nationalNumber=nationalNumber
            )
           #OR
           form.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass the actual data to the form

```
form = CommentForm(data={ "email": email, "text": text })
if form.is_valid()
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.author = request.user
    instance.save()
```

Comment: Hey bro, It, s still not working..  I don't know how can I map these two to the same URLs. I got frustrated from two days now.. Basically I have a detail view which displays the post and below there is comment section which I try to get the post request in that detail view it shows me error and than I make a different view for comments but I don't know How will that map to that same page and same URL and how will I insert that in HTML..